# Sitecore 9.2 Helix ,How to use Assets, SitecoreExtension and Dependency Injection that exist in foundation layer of habitat

Tags: sitecore, helix, sitecore-habitat

I am beginner to development in sitecore using Helix Design Principle
i started with blank project and added one feature in feature layer and one layout in project layer [as in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D4Dd.png)  and it works fine.

my issue when i tried to use asset module for styling purpose that exists in foundation layer of habitat to my project, it told me that it needs Dependency Injection and Sitecore Extension

and when i try to load DependenyInjection inside my project , and deploy it with gulpfile [as in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gVaA.png),the sitecore gave me that error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not load file or assembly 'Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:


Line 187:            try
Line 188:            {
Line 189:                return assembly.GetExportedTypes();
Line 190:            }
Line 191:            catch (NotSupportedException)

Source File: D:\Ejada Files\NewsEjada - Copy - Copy\src\Foundation\DependencyInjection\code\ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs    Line: 189

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace:


[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes() +32
   Sitecore.Foundation.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.GetExportedTypes(Assembly assembly) in D:\Ejada Files\NewsEjada - Copy - Copy\src\Foundation\DependencyInjection\code\ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs:189

[InvalidOperationException: Unable to load types from assembly Sitecore.XA.JSS.Foundation.Integration, Version=5.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. Could not load file or assembly 'Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   Sitecore.Foundation.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.GetExportedTypes(Assembly assembly) in D:\Ejada Files\NewsEjada - Copy - Copy\src\Foundation\DependencyInjection\code\ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs:210
   System.Linq.<SelectManyIterator>d__17`2.MoveNext() +265
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +287
   System.Linq.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() +255
   Sitecore.Foundation.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddClassesWithServiceAttribute(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, Assembly[] assemblies) in D:\Ejada Files\NewsEjada - Copy - Copy\src\Foundation\DependencyInjection\code\ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs:39
   Sitecore.Foundation.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddClassesWithServiceAttribute(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, String[] assemblyFilters) in D:\Ejada Files\NewsEjada - Copy - Copy\src\Foundation\DependencyInjection\code\ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs:27
   Sitecore.Foundation.DependencyInjection.Infrastructure.MvcControllerServicesConfigurator.Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection) in D:\Ejada Files\NewsEjada - Copy - Copy\src\Foundation\DependencyInjection\code\Infrastructure\MvcControllerServicesConfigurator.cs:12
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServicesConfiguratorFactory.Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection) +171
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServicesConfiguratorFactory.Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection) +171
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServiceProviderBuilder.ConfigureServiceCollection() +142
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.ConfigureServiceProvider() +225
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.get_ServiceProvider() +513
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.SitecorePerRequestScopeModule..ctor() +13

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +142
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +107
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +1476
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +186
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture) +28
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[] args) +80
   System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList) +234
   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext) +1153
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +139
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +277
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +369

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +724
```

Comment: Did you find the cause of this error??

Answer (score 0):

First, take a look at [this sitecore community question](https://community.sitecore.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=1ab5af2d1b4770d0b8954371b24bcb35) as it feels similar to your case.

Then, if not fixed :

- Make sure you have added the sitecore nuget source (https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/api/v3/index.json) in your visual studio using nuget package manager -> Package Sources.
- Add this source to your nuget.config within your solution as well.
- Make sure you don't have any of those following dependencies already installed with some other reference within your project

  ```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" Version="5.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" Version="3.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" Version="3.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" Version="1.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" Version="1.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" Version="1.0.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.Debug" Version="4.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Globalization" Version="4.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Expressions" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Resources.ResourceManager" Version="4.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  ```

From habitat project [repos](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/src/Foundation/Assets/code/Sitecore.Foundation.Assets.csproj)